# How to count elements ignoring whether they are children or siblings?

Tags: xslt-1.0

This might be a novice question but, then again, I'm a novice :-)

### OLD SITUATION:

I have XML files in this format:

```
<chapter>
  <title>chapter title</title>
  <para>p1</para>
  <para>p2</para>
  <para>p3</para>

    <!-- ....and so on for a lot of para elements -->

</chapter>
```

...which are handled by an XSL template like this...

```
<xsl:template match="para">   
   <xsl:if test="count(following-sibling::para) = 1 and count(preceding-sibling::para) &gt; 13">
       <!-- Insert Some Stuff -->
   </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

The logic here is: "Insert Some Stuff" before the second-to-last  element if there are enough preceding <para> siblings.

This code gets the job done and works fine.

---

### NEW SITUATION

Now, for reasons beyond my control, I need to adapt that template to handle the following kind of files as well...

```
<chapter>
  <title>chapter title</title>
  <para>p1</para>
  <para>p2</para>
  <para>p3</para>
  <section>
     <para>p4</para>
     <para>p5</para>
  </section>
  <para>p6</para>
  <section>
     <title>section title</title> 
  </section>
  <para>p7</para>
  <section>
     <para>p8</para>
  </section>

  <!-- ....and so on for a lot of para elements -->

</chapter>
```

The difference with these files is that the <section> element can appear randomly, sometimes containing <para> elements and sometimes not. There is no way of predicting when and where <section> elements will appear.

I need the original XSL template to work with this format in the same way despite the <section> elements being there. So that means that the <para> elements still need to be counted in the same way even if they are sometimes children and sometimes siblings.

**In summary, I need the logic of the old code to work as before, as though it is completely ignoring the presence of the <section> elements.**

**What should the original template  <xsl:if test="..."> be rewritten as to make this work?**

Performance is not an issue - these are manually-run ad-hoc transformations.

**XSLT 1.0 only, please**

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is difficult to answer your question without seeing a complete stylesheet and the expected output/s.

Would not:

```
<xsl:template match="para">   
   <xsl:if test="count(following::para) = 1 and count(preceding::para) &gt; 13">
       <!-- Insert Some Stuff -->
   </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

work for you?

---

### Added:

> If you're sure that what you've suggested should work for the example
>   given in the question

Well, the example given in the question does not have the required minimum of `para` nodes - but if we reduce the threshold:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="para"> 
    <xsl:if test="count(following::para) = 1 and count(preceding::para) &gt; 5">
        <INSERTED_NODE/>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Test Input A**

```
<chapter>
  <title>Section Title 1</title>
  <para>Para 1</para>
  <para>Para 2</para>
  <para>Para 3</para>
  <section>
    <title>Section Title 2</title>
    <para>Para 4</para>
    <para>Para 5</para>
  </section>
  <para>Para 6</para>
  <section>
    <title>Section Title 3</title>
    <para>Para 7</para>
    <para>Para 8</para>
  </section>
  <para>Para 9</para>
  <para>Para 10</para>
</chapter>
```

**Result A**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<chapter>
   <title>Section Title 1</title>
   <para>Para 1</para>
   <para>Para 2</para>
   <para>Para 3</para>
   <section>
      <title>Section Title 2</title>
      <para>Para 4</para>
      <para>Para 5</para>
   </section>
   <para>Para 6</para>
   <section>
      <title>Section Title 3</title>
      <para>Para 7</para>
      <para>Para 8</para>
   </section>
   <INSERTED_NODE/>
   <para>Para 9</para>
   <para>Para 10</para>
</chapter>
```

**Test Input B**

```
<chapter>
  <title>Section Title 1</title>
  <para>Para 1</para>
  <para>Para 2</para>
  <para>Para 3</para>
  <section>
    <title>Section Title 2</title>
    <para>Para 4</para>
    <para>Para 5</para>
  </section>
  <para>Para 6</para>
  <section>
    <title>Section Title 3</title>
    <para>Para 7</para>
    <para>Para 8</para>
  </section>
  <para>Para 9</para>
</chapter>
```

**Result B**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<chapter>
   <title>Section Title 1</title>
   <para>Para 1</para>
   <para>Para 2</para>
   <para>Para 3</para>
   <section>
      <title>Section Title 2</title>
      <para>Para 4</para>
      <para>Para 5</para>
   </section>
   <para>Para 6</para>
   <section>
      <title>Section Title 3</title>
      <para>Para 7</para>
      <INSERTED_NODE/>
      <para>Para 8</para>
   </section>
   <para>Para 9</para>
</chapter>
```

---

### Edit

> Is there a way to force it to be inserted once per chapter element?

Yes, you could do it this way:

```
<xsl:template match="para"> 
    <xsl:variable name="i">
        <xsl:number count="para" from="chapter" level="any"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="n" select="count(ancestor::chapter//para)" />   
    <xsl:if test="$i + 1 = $n and $n &gt; 5">
        <INSERTED_NODE/>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

A more efficient solution would do the counting once at the chapter level, and pass it down as a parameter to the paras.

Comment: I've tried that previously and just that single change stops the "Insert Some Stuff" being triggered at all. I can't really post the entire stylesheet here - it's fairly large and parts are commercially sensitive. I've put the essence of the problem in the question. If you're sure that what you've suggested should work for the example given in the question, I guess there might be something else interfering with this template match. I can try stripping out as much as possible from that stylesheet and see if that changes the behaviour.

Comment: @Joe See the addendum to my post.

Comment: Thank you. I'll mark this as accepted answer since it answers the original question. I'll have to strip down the stylesheet I've got until it starts working as it should

Comment: Having done some detective work, I can see what's happening now. I have a large number of chapter elements and the INSERTED_NODE is only appearing in the last chapter, though in the right place...which makes sense considering the test is only para-element-based. Is there a way to force it to be inserted once per chapter element?